# Is there a way to have a ASP.NET Button with a dropdown menu?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, drop-down-menu, aspbutton

I am trying to place a button on a webform in which when I click on it a submenu will appear giving me other options to navigate on my application. Is there any way to do it?
Can you place sample code please.

Comment: No. You could either use a `DropDownList` or try to achieve this with JavaScript.

Comment: Can you do it: Yes.  It's going to take a bit of javascript.  When the button is pressed you will need to show a div that contains this submenu you want.  Hook into the buttons onclick handler and, because this is asp.net, make sure that it `returns false;` so that the form isn't submitted.

Comment: You should post some code of what you've tried already. It's not good [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) practice to post questions without first trying or researching yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/MXkCb/

`<input type="button" value="show more options" class="showmore"/>
<div><ul>
    <li>option 1</li>
    <li>option 2</li>
    <li>option 3</li>
    <li>option 4</li>
</ul></div>`

`$('.showmore').on('click', function(){
    $('div').show("slow");
});`

Answer (score 0):

In your view, try this:

@ {
var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.TwoLetterISOLanguageName })
.ToList();

}

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown title
    </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        
  @foreach (var culture in cultureItems)
  {
                                                
    <form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="Home"
      asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path"
     method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <input class="dropdown-item  waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="culture" value="@culture.Value" />       
    </form>
  }
 </div>

</li>
```